# Import and reuse existing struct from different package

Tags: go

I need to import the existing struct from different package that lives in vendor folder. My folder stucture is below

```
       projectname
           custom
              custom.go
           vendor
              github.com
                somepackage
                   authentication
                    models.go
```

the models.go contains this struct

```golang
package authentication

type User struct {
        ID           int64
        AccessToken  string
        Email        string
        FullName     string
        Password     string
        PasswordHash string
        PasswordSalt string
        Readonly     bool
        Role         Role
        Token        string
        Username     string
}
```

Now inside my custom/custom.go, I have a function that follows a signature and the code looks like this

Signature

```golang
type loginFn func(string, string) (*User, error)
```

I import like this

```golang
import "github.com/somepackage/authentication/models"

func SetupGoGuardian(u, p string) (*User, error) {
```

But I got error coud not import ...... (no required module provides package)

How to properly import the struct from another package and use it a custom function?

Comment: I read golang docs for a week, start coding after reading it. Then start creating project to actually learn it. Stumbled some difficulties, tried googling to find possible solutions, got none,then finally asked a question here in stackoverflow to get some help, then gets downvoted.. :)

Comment: XD.! Welcome to stackoverflow.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot import files, only packages. Change your import statement to reference the package name:

```golang
import "github.com/somepackage/authentication"
```